# What does the second solution in an elastic collision represent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

A ball of mass 2 collides with a  stationary ball of mass 1 elastically!

In finding the velocities i end up with two solutions and am not sure how to understand the second solution

Simplified equation of Energy

1) $ 2v^2 = 2v^{`2} + v_b^2 $

Simplified equation of Momentum

2) $ 2v = 2v^` + v_b$

Now solving for vb

$v_b = 2v - 2v^`$

squarring and inserting into eq 1

$2v^2 = 2v^{`2} + 4v^2 -8vv^` +4v^{`2}$

solving

$0 = 2v^{`2} +2v^2-8vv^` +4v^{`2}$

$0 = 2v^2-8vv^` + 6v^{`2} $

$0 = v^2-4vv^` + 3v^{`2} $

$0 = (v - 3v^`)(v - v^`)$

Now the dilema, it makes sense that our original speed on ball 1 would be a third, but what is the second answer trying to say?

$v/3=v^`$

$v=v^`$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution will mathematically satisfy the conservation equations, but corresponds the objects not actually colliding. Or they ``ghost'' and fly right through each other. :)

Comment: man i have to learn to think out of the box thanks for the help